# Reference request: relationship between c-convexity and geodesic convexity on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, optimal-transport

I am interested in a characterization of c-convex/c-concave functions (as in Definition 5.2 and Definition 5.7 in Cédric Villani's book, ['Optimal transport, old and new'](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf)) on manifolds in the case when the cost function is the half squared distance, $c(x, y) = \frac{1}{2} \text{dist}^2(x, y)$.

In particular, in [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/a/438821/496670) it is mentioned that on a manifold of nonnegative sectional curvature, a c-convex function $f$ is 1-convex, i.e. $ g(t) = f(\gamma(t)) + \frac{t^2}{2} $ is convex, where $ \gamma $ is a unit speed geodesic. Does anyone know of a reference where this property is explored?

Thank you!